# Apache Flink DataStream API doesn't have a mapPartition transformation

Tags: apache-flink

Spark DStream has `mapPartition` API, while Flink `DataStream` API doesn't. Is there anyone who could help explain the reason. What I want to do is to implement a API similar to Spark `reduceByKey` on Flink.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Flink's stream processing model is quite different from Spark Streaming which is centered around mini batches. In Spark Streaming each mini batch is executed like a regular batch program on a finite set of data, whereas Flink DataStream programs continuously process records.

In Flink's DataSet API, a `MapPartitionFunction` has two parameters. An iterator for the input and a collector for the result of the function. A `MapPartitionFunction` in a Flink DataStream program would never return from the first function call, because the iterator would iterate over an endless stream of records. However, Flink's internal stream processing model requires that user functions return in order to checkpoint function state. Therefore, the DataStream API does not offer a `mapPartition` transformation.

In order to implement functionality similar to Spark Streaming's `reduceByKey`, you need to define a keyed window over the stream. Windows discretize streams which is somewhat similar to mini batches but windows offer way more flexibility. Since a window is of finite size, you can call `reduce` the window.

This could look like:

```
yourStream.keyBy("myKey") // organize stream by key "myKey"
          .timeWindow(Time.seconds(5)) // build 5 sec tumbling windows
          .reduce(new YourReduceFunction); // apply a reduce function on each window
```

The [DataStream documentation](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-master/apis/streaming_guide.html) shows how to define various window types and explains all available functions.

**Note:** The DataStream API has been reworked recently. The example assumes the latest version (0.10-SNAPSHOT) which will be release as 0.10.0 in the next days.

Comment: It seems that the solution of 'reduceByKey' you provided is similar to 'GroupByKey' in spark other than 'reduceByKey'.  https://databricks.gitbooks.io/databricks-spark-knowledge-base/content/best_practices/prefer_reducebykey_over_groupbykey.html

Comment: No, Flink's `reduce()` applies like Spark's `reduceByKey` a pair-wise reduce function on a group. The group definition is a bit different though, because Flink uses windows and Spark key-value pairs in mini batches. There is no direct equivalent to Spark's `groupByKey` in Flink, because this implies that the full group needs to be materialized in memory, which can lead to OutOfMemoryErrors and kill the JVM. Flink offers `groupReduce()` to consume a streamed iterator.

Comment: I see Flink's reduce() applies combinable. Is it similar reason that Flink DataStream doesn't have reduceGroup API as mapPartition?

Comment: Yes and no :-). Yes for non-windowed streams, because they are of infinite length and the `groupReduce` method would never return. No for windowed streams (windows are of finite length) where the `apply()` method is essentially a `groupReduce` function that additionally provides some meta data of the window.

Comment: Thanks, it seems that I couldn't find such apply method you mentioned.

Comment: [DataStream API Documentation: Window Apply](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-master/apis/streaming_guide.html#transformations)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your input stream is single partition data (say String)

```
val new_number_of_partitions = 4

//below line partitions your data, you can broadcast data to all partitions
val step1stream = yourStream.rescale.setParallelism(new_number_of_partitions)

//flexibility for mapping
val step2stream = step1stream.map(new RichMapFunction[String, (String, Int)]{
  // var local_val_to_different_part : Type = null
  var myTaskId : Int = null

  //below function is executed once for each mapper function (one mapper per partition)
  override def open(config: Configuration): Unit = {
    myTaskId = getRuntimeContext.getIndexOfThisSubtask
    //do whatever initialization you want to do. read from data sources..
  }

  def map(value: String): (String, Int) = {
    (value, myTasKId)
  }
})

val step3stream = step2stream.keyBy(0).countWindow(new_number_of_partitions).sum(1).print
//Instead of sum(1), you can use .reduce((x,y)=>(x._1,x._2+y._2))
//.countWindow will first wait for a certain number of records for perticular key
// and then apply the function
```

Flink streaming is pure streaming (not the batched one). Take a look at Iterate API.