# Apache Flink: MapPartition Vs. FlatMap

Tags: hadoop, apache-flink

I did not get clear understanding of MapPartition. Please somebody explain with some use case of Mappartition and how it is different from FlatMap ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The difference is in the interface of the methods and how they are called.

- `FlatMapFunction`'s `flatMap(IN val, Collector<OUT> out)` method is called for each record and can emit `0`, `1`, or more records for each input record. Hence, a `FlatMapFunction` processes records one-by-one. It should not keep state across function invocations.
- `MapPartitionFunction`'s `mapPartition(Iterable<IN> vals, Collector<OUT> out)` method is called just once and receives an iterator over all partitions. It can emit `0`, `1`, or more records for the whole partition. Hence, a `MapPartitionFunction` can (in principle) collect the whole partition and compute a result. However, if a partition is large, this can be dangerous because you can run easily out of memory. mapPartition is often useful if you sort the partitions first.

So, in general, `mapPartition` is more generic and can do everything that `flatMap` does and more. However, as with many powerful tools, you need to be more careful because you can shot yourself in the foot. The `flatMap` interface is safer (and usually easier) to use.

Comment: Thanks fabian for explanation.                                                                    So in general mapPartition should be faster than flatMap in terms of performance is it correct ?.  As you explained mapParition collect the whole partition , here i have a doubt as per my understanding no of map in flink is not depend on splits and it depends on parallelism. so if parallelism is less than the no. of splits than some mapPartition will assign more than one input splits. so all splits it collect as a single iterable means multiple splits make a input partition.

Comment: Splits and partitions are not the same in Flink. Each parallel instance of an operator processes one partition, i.e., a partition might consists of multiple splits. MapPartition does **not** collect all data in memory (unless your user function does that). The partition is streamed through the Iterable. Its probably a little bit more efficient than flatMap, but as I said, you have to be careful. If your not explicitly partition you data, the result can be non-deterministic.

Comment: great got it. Please just give me detail about how splits are get assigned to partitions , if i do not explicitly partition my data and  no .of partitions is same as  parallelism of operator.

Comment: Flink's source operators work differently than Hadoop's. Flink starts a fixed number of source tasks (as many as the parallelism of the operator) and lazily assigns input splits to these source tasks with locality preference (if available). So a source task processes multiple input splits and there is no deterministic mapping of splits to source tasks or partitions (since a task processes one partition, task = partition in this case).

Comment: Thanks a lot fabian for clearing many doubts. Can you suggest some good source to understand these flink internals more in depth.

Answer (score 0):

> In Apache Flink you can act on either a `DataSet` or a `DataStream`

`flatMap` is a function call on each record of either of the two

```
.flatMap(new Tokenizer())  // calling on each record   
.flatMap(String value, Collector<Tuple2<String, Integer>> out) //definition
```

whereas,

`mapPartition` is a map and for loop on every partition till all the records in the partition for a Key are processed

> DataStream does not have a mapPartition available in the API

For more information read [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33401332/apache-flink-datastream-api-doesnt-have-a-mappartition-transformation)